# JQuery on scroll moving images

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scroll

Maybe this looks very basic. I'm sorry but I'm not sure why this code is not compiling. I need to mention I'm very new to jQuery. I tried for the second `$("document")` to use id of div "content" but neither that one is working.

Can you please provide me a solution? 
Many thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Using jQuery Animations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("document").ready(function() {
            $( "document" ).scroll(function() {

                $("#background")
                .animate({left: 20, top:10}, 1000)
                $("#brackets")
                .animate({left: 20, top:10}, 1000)

        });
     });   

    </script>
    <style>
        #content {position: relative;}
        #background {
            background: #333;
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            position: absolute;
            width: 450px;
            height: 400px;

        }

         #brackets {
            background: transparent;
            border: 3px solid #000;
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            position: absolute;
            width: 450px;
            height: 400px;
            left: 50px;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body style="height:100px; padding-top:400px;">

    <div id="content">
        <div id="background"></div>
        <div id="brackets"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$( "document" ).scroll(function() {
```

With:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a selector of `"document"` to the [jQuery DOM selector function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1), use the `window` object:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
```

See it demonstrated below:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#console').append("scrolling<br />")
    $("#background")
      .animate({
        left: 20,
        top: 10
      }, 1000)
    $("#brackets")
      .animate({
        left: 20,
        top: 10
      }, 1000)

  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
}

#background {
  background: #333;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
}

#brackets {
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="background"></div>
  <div id="brackets"></div>
</div>
<div id="console"></div>
```